# Get CDATA from BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, cdata

I have a HTML source code with a CDATA tag that has some info I would like to have.

When I try the following:

```
switch_url = switch_soup.find_all(text=re.compile(('Switches')))
```

I get this output:

```
['//<![CDATA[\n    "url":"https://xxxx.meraki.com/xxxxxxx/n/xxxxx/manage/nodes/list","name":"Switches","admin_only":false},{"is_current":false,"url":"https://nxx.meraki.com/xxxxx/n/xxxxx/manage/configure/switchports","name":"Switch ports","admin_only":false},{"is_current":false,"url":"https://xxxx.meraki.com/Dormitory/n/xxxxxxx/manage/configure/dhcp_servers"//]]>\n  ']
```

How can I acquire the "Switches" url, which is: "https://xxxx.meraki.com/xxxxxxx/n/xxxxx/manage/nodes/list" from the CDATA output?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this

```py
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

// source.html contains your html above
f = open('source.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(f.readlines()))
cdata = soup.find(text=re.compile("CDATA"))
```

or you can try this

```py
for script in soup(['script', 'style']):
        script.decompose()

    text = soup.get_text()
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
```